# -32603: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, ganache

I am using Ganache and Ethereum Remix

Here is my solidity smart contract function:

```
function sendEth(string memory url) public payable{
    require(msg.value >= minLimit, "Pay more than the minimum limit");
}
```

And I am calling it with react code, here is my react code:

```
return erc20Contract.methods
    .sendEth(url)
    .send({
      from: walletAddress, 
      value: 120000000 // Hardcoded value for testing
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log("Success", res)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err)) ;
```

I am getting this error when I try to sign using metamask:

[Metamask Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chOAu.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twjPz.png)

Getting same error on Remix too

[Remix Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olo73.png)

What is the reason of this error?

Comment: What is the value of `minLimit`?

Comment: Oh Yes, I got it, thanks. The ETH transfer value was less than MinLimit. 
It supposed to print the statement, right?